# .htaccess URL Rewriting suffix removal

Tags: php, .htaccess

when I attempt to remove the suffix .html from

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /images.php?id=$1 [L]
```

it just breaks all the code, how should I go about fixing this?

I'm basically trying to get an image id, which is already done, but the suffix is stuck there.

Where I header to the tag -

```
        echo header( "Location: http://example.com/$newfilename.html");
```

Comment: Well, yes, you're rewriting ***all*** files ending in .html to a PHP script. That may probably break some things, if you expect to use other .html files directly. It's unclear what this is supposed to be doing instead, you'll have to clarify what you need this to do.

Comment: Here's the site if this clears anything up http://imgids.com/
Basically need the images.php page to just show the IMG id without the .html extension